# Convert CSV file to JSON dictionary?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

I need to convert a large CSV data set to JSON, however the output should be a JSON dictionary like this:

```
var products = {
    "crystal": {
        "description": "This is a crystal",
        "price": "2.95"
    },
    "emerald": {
        "description": "This is a emerald",
        "price": "5.95"
    }
};
```

This is what the CSV table would look like:
[image]

I am using a script referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759516/convert-large-csv-files-to-json) to generate the JSON:

```
var csv = require('csv')
var fs = require('fs')
var f = fs.createReadStream('Fielding.csv')
var w = fs.createWriteStream('out.txt')

w.write('[');

csv()
.from.stream(f, {columns:true})
.transform(function(row, index) {
    return (index === 0 ? '' : ',\n') + JSON.stringify(row);
})
.to.stream(w, {columns: true, end: false})
.on('end', function() {
     w.write(']');
     w.end();
 });
```

However the output from that script is created in this format:

```
[
    {
        "name": "crystal",
        "description": "This is a crystal",
        "price": "2.95"
    },
    {
        "name": "emerald",
        "description": "This is a emerald",
        "price": "5.95"
    }
]
```

How would I modify the script to get my desired "dictionary" format?

Comment: Not sure how you even ended up with that structure since columns, and thus property names, are normally the same

Comment: Please edit your question to include a sample of the actual CSV data you're working with.

Comment: Is there some kind of pattern in the names of the product, like `productX` where X is a number, or is it pretty random ?

Comment: Sorry - edited. Essentially the "name" column would go away and the name value becomes the name of the object.

Comment: just iterate array and pass `item.name` as property key in new object

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is loop over the array and use `item.name` as key for your dictionary object

```
var products ={};

data.forEach(function(item){
     products[item.name] = item;
});
```

This will leave the `name` property in the item but that shouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 2):

I found [csv parser](http://csv.adaltas.com/parse/) library most useful:

```
var csvText=`status,path,name,ext,checksum,size,document_service_id,document_service_path,message
success,./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE1.txt,expE1.txt,txt,38441337865069eabae7754b29bb43e1,414984,8269f7e3-3221-49bb-bb5a-5796cf208fd1,/neuroinftest/20170215/expE1.txt,
success,./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE10.txt,expE10.txt,txt,f27e46979035706eb0aaf58c26e09585,368573,2c94ed19-29c9-4660-83cf-c2148c3d6f61,/neuroinftest/20170215/expE10.txt,
success,./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE2.txt,expE2.txt,txt,e1040d9546423c823944120de0e5c46c,333308,b3898f5d-1058-4cf3-acf9-76759117b810,/neuroinftest/20170215/expE2.txt,
`
var csv = require('csv');
csv.parse(csvText, {columns: true}, function(err, data){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

In variable `csvText` I have my comma-separated file, with the first line serving as a header. I use the `parse` function and I'm passing the `{columns: true}` to indicated that the first line has the headers. Second parameter in the callback function (`data`) has the object with keys being the headers and the values being the corresponding csv cells. I use `JSON.stringify` to print it nicely and the result object looks like this (it puts it into an array):

```
[
  {
    "status": "success",
    "path": "./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE1.txt",
    "name": "expE1.txt",
    "ext": "txt",
    "checksum": "38441337865069eabae7754b29bb43e1",
    "size": "414984",
    "document_service_id": "8269f7e3-3221-49bb-bb5a-5796cf208fd1",
    "document_service_path": "/neuroinftest/20170215/expE1.txt",
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "status": "success",
    "path": "./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE10.txt",
    "name": "expE10.txt",
    "ext": "txt",
    "checksum": "f27e46979035706eb0aaf58c26e09585",
    "size": "368573",
    "document_service_id": "2c94ed19-29c9-4660-83cf-c2148c3d6f61",
    "document_service_path": "/neuroinftest/20170215/expE10.txt",
    "message": ""
  },
  {
    "status": "success",
    "path": "./15-02-2017_17-11/d77c7886-ffe9-40f2-b2fe-e68410d07891//expE2.txt",
    "name": "expE2.txt",
    "ext": "txt",
    "checksum": "e1040d9546423c823944120de0e5c46c",
    "size": "333308",
    "document_service_id": "b3898f5d-1058-4cf3-acf9-76759117b810",
    "document_service_path": "/neuroinftest/20170215/expE2.txt",
    "message": ""
  }
]
```

**UPD**: This array can easily be turned into the object you need with `reduce`:

```
var res_obj = data.reduce(function(acc, cur, i) {
  acc[cur.name] = cur;
  return acc;
}, {});
```

In my case I use the name property as a key. Make sure it's unique.

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this would work :

```
var products_arr = [{"name":"crystal","description":"This is a crystal","price":"2.95"},
 {"name":"emerald","description":"This is a emerald","price":"5.95"}]
var products = {};

for (var i = 0, l = products_arr.length ; i < l ; ++i) {
    var x = products_arr[i];
    var name = x.name
    delete x.name; // deletes name property from JSON object
    products[name] = x;
}
```

This will output :

```
{
  "crystal": {
    "description": "This is a crystal",
    "price": "2.95"
  },
  "emerald": {
    "description": "This is a emerald",
    "price": "5.95"
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer starts from the incorrect output generated by the OP's current script.  However, the OP is asking how they would modify their original node code which reads the csv.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to modify your specific code, you could change the line

```
 return (index === 0 ? '' : ',\n') + JSON.stringify(row);
```

to

```
 var clonedRow = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(row));
 var key = clonedRow['name'];
 delete clonedRow['name'];
 var newRow = {};
 newRow[key] = clonedRow;
 return (index === 0 ? '' : ',\n') + JSON.stringify(newRow);
```

This creates a new object for each row, modifying the structure according to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet is to use [PapaParse](http://papaparse.com/), a powerful csv parser/dumper. It supports streams, various string encodings, header row, and it's fast.

Comment: all this does is provide a library link, doesn't provide code to solve issue using that library. This *answer* is really nothing more than a comment