# CSV to JSON benchmarks

Tags: json, csv, converters

I'm working on a project that uses parallel methods to convert text from one form to another. We're going to implement a CSV to JSON converter to demonstrate the speedups that are possible using our parallel framework.

We want to benchmark our converter once it's finished. What are the fastest libraries/stand-alone programs/etc out there that are capable of doing CSV-JSON conversion? I found a list of potential candidates here:[Large CSV to JSON/Object in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617532/large-csv-to-json-object-in-node-js), but I'm not sure how fast the listed options are. In the worst case I'll benchmark them myself, but if someone already knows what the "best in class" converters are it'd save me some time.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the maintainer of [csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson) has developed a [benchmark application](https://github.com/Keyang/csvbench). I think I can add my csv to json converter to his benchmark project to test my converter.

Answer (score 0):

if your project can consider in-browser apps, I suggest [csvtojson](http://csvtojson.com) as it is by far the speediest converter on the market as of 2017.

I created it myself so I may be a bit biaised, but I specifically developed it for a bigger project that required big csv to json crunching.

Tell me if it served.

Comment: is there any way to run your converter from the command line? That would make it easier to benchmark.